# Allow Webview To Redirect In iOS React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native

I have been searching the web all through the week but can't seem to find a way to make the Webview in React Native allow page redirection on iOS, currently have a payment gateway that does a lot of redirects on the server side when the payment form is submitted, but every time it gets to the point of redirecting to another page, the Webview just stops loading. Found a solution for Android that works fine, but none for iOS, has anyone here tackled this kind of issue before or have a fix for it? Will really appreciate as I'm near the point of total frustration right now.

Please find below my implementation.

```
<WebView
   ref="webview"
   javaScriptEnabled={true}
   onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
   source={{uri: this._getPaymentUrl()}}
   style={[Styles.misc.spanned]}
   renderLoading={() => { return ... } }
   renderError={() => { return ... }}
   startInLoadingState={true} />
```

Although I assume if a change will be made to make this work it has to be from a Swift code somewhere, please really stuck on this, all week.

It can load a page normally but when there is a redirect in between requests it just stops navigating and does nothing.

Comment: Is there a javascript error when the webview stops loading as you say? I suggest you debug the Webview to see what happens upon redirection. Plus some code example on how you use the WebView would be helpful here

Comment: @needsleep have added my implementation and some explanation to it, hope this helps to make it clearer, thanks!

Comment: This is strange, I think the reason the webview stops loading as you say might have to do with a js error or the way the redirection is implemented. Unfortunately I can't help you if I don't have the url you load in your webview. How did you solve this on Android?

Comment: Funny thing, updated React Native to 0.54.1 and now it works.
For Android I used this package. 
https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-webview-android/
Don't know whether this can go as an answer even.
Thanks for your time, I really appreciate.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I had several problems with RN Webview but none as what you described, that's why your issue caught my attention.